# Keyboard sometimes blocks UITextView

Tags: ios, keyboard, scroll, textview

In my app I have a UITextView that is in the bottom part of the screen. So what I do is the following code but the issue is, only sometimes if the text that I click on the UITextView is below the keyboard, it will scroll properly to above the keyboard.

Here is how I register the NSNotifications:
(In the ViewDidLoad)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

The methods:

```
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    // Resize the scroll view (which is the root view of the window)
    CGRect viewFrame = [textView frame];

    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;

    textView.frame = viewFrame;

    // Scroll the active text field into view.
    //CGRect textFieldRect = [activeField frame];
    [textView scrollRectToVisible:viewFrame animated:YES];
}

-(void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    // Reset the height of the scroll view to its original value
    CGRect viewFrame = [textView frame];
    viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
    textView.frame = viewFrame;
}
```

How I unregister the NSNotifications:
In the ViewDidUnload:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is only sometimes that the scroll doesn't happen, check your frame calculation and movement. It might go wrong.

Comment: What should I NSLog, I will post it because all these values are very confusing. Maybe someone else will see my issues when I post those values.

Comment: You should print your original view frame, keyboard size and finally modified view frame.

Comment: I ended up fixing this but I am facing a similar problem except this time with UITextField in custom UITableViewCell's.

Comment: You should post your answer

Answer (score 0):

here is the code I use to move the textview up so I can see it when the KB shows up. my view is in a scrollview already.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { //Keyboard becomes visible

    //perform actions.
    NSLog(@"IN VIEW");
    [self scrollTheViewToTop:self.scroller forTheTextView:textView];
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.scroller setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
- (void)scrollTheViewToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView forTheTextView:(UITextView *)textView {

    //Scroll the ScrollView Up tp show the Continue button in the bottom is visible.

    CGPoint pt;
    CGRect rc = [textView bounds];
    rc = [textView convertRect:rc toView:scrollView];
    pt = rc.origin;
    pt.x = 0;
    pt.y -= 60;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
}
```